# Replace \\n \\r \\t posted in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping

I have a inout text field where user can copy paste data, I want to replace `\r \n \t` but when the data is posted these characters are escaped.

So a string entered by user for example `hello \r\n\t world` is posted as `hello \\r\\n\\t world`

I want to replace these characters but because they are escaped I am not able to use something like `gsub(/\s+/, ' ')`

Can anyone suggest what would be a ideal way to replace the escaped characters.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's posted that way? The string `\r` will look like `"\\r"` in `inspect` mode. This is just how Ruby presents it, and other languages follow the same conventions. Do you mean people are submitting literally *backslash r* or are you talking about the carriage return character.

Comment: yes, its posted that way, user can copy text from other applications which can have these characters and each of the character is escaped and posted to the rails controller action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting literally *backslash-r* you'll need to de-map these:

```
CONVERT = {
  '\r' => "\r",
  '\t' => "\t",
  '\n' => "\n"
}

CONVERT_RX = Regexp.union(CONVERT.keys)

'this\nis\tinput\r\n'.gsub(CONVERT_RX, CONVERT)
# => "this\nis\tinput\r\n"
```

You can add more entries to that table as necessary.

From there if you want to strip or convert spaces you can do that as you would normally.